# How do I make it so the cells in a CSS grid row are all the same height across columns?

Tags: html, css, grid

Trying to search this is impossible -- every answer is about a slightly different problem, which is making it so all the rows in a single column are the same height (i.e. the same height as the tallest cell in that column). They say to add `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` to the grid container. That's true and works, but isn't what I'm describing.

Here, I'll send a sample code that demonstrates what I'm talking about. I wanted the "aaa" cell to be the same height as the "BBB" cell, for the "ccc" cell to be the same height as the "DDD" cell, ... .

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 600px;
  gap: 2px;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: #fea;
}

.bigger-text {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">aaa</div>
  <div class="grid-item bigger-text">BBB</div>
  <div class="grid-item">ccc</div>
  <div class="grid-item bigger-text">DDD</div>
  <div class="grid-item">eee</div>
  <div class="grid-item bigger-text">FFF</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want cell aaa to be the same height as cell BBB, then your description of your goal is incorrect where you say "making it so all the rows in a single column are the same height". Perhaps what you meant to say was "making it so all the cells in a single row are the same height"?

Comment: The goal is: all the cells of a row, should be the same across columns (the cells in a row are all in different columns). Isn't this right?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is solely caused by `align-items: center` which sets the height to the content and then vertically centering the item.

You can use `flexbox to center the text if you need:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 600px;
  gap: 2px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: #fea;
  /* vertically centers text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.bigger-text {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">aaa</div>
  <div class="grid-item bigger-text">BBB</div>
  <div class="grid-item">ccc</div>
  <div class="grid-item bigger-text">DDD</div>
  <div class="grid-item">eee</div>
  <div class="grid-item bigger-text">FFF</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want the cells in a css grid row to have the same height across columns, you can set the align-self property for each item to stretch. this will make each item in the row stretch to match the height of the tallest item in that row. here is the modified code:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 600px;
  gap: 2px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: #fea;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.bigger-text {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: This sounds oddly like an AI phrasing. That wouldd also explain why you technical wrong. The whole issue is caused by `align-items: center` which you removed on your own. So there is no further need for your solution as it does nothing that the default grid would do by itself.